# A problem in Combinatorial Analysis

Tags: combinatorics

It's a question of a exercise list...

Let A be a set with n points on the plane such that for each point P of A there are at least k points in A equidistant to P. Prove that

$$k < \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2n}$$

If someone could give hint or a solution, it would be really helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need the extra condition: (i) No three points of $A$ lie on a straight line.

This problem in fact appeared in IMO 1989. Here is a solution (taken from the book *IMO Compendium* by Dušan Djukić, Vladimir Janković, Ivan Matić, Nikola Petrović):

[image]

Comment: Hmm... not a very satisfying proof, just a verification. I wonder if it's possible to improve the bound on $k$?

Comment: The condition is not necessary...